# How to get a statement calling the function from inside the function itself?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, postgresql-9.1

Let's say I have a function `show_files(IN file text, IN suffix text, OUT statement text)`. In next step the function is called:

```
 SELECT * FROM show_files(file := 'example', suffix := '.png');
```

My question is: Is there any solution that I could get statement that has called this function from inside that function?

I mean, after running the `SELECT` the output of function `(OUT statement text)` should be: `'SELECT * FROM show_files(file := 'example', suffix := '.png');'`, or is it possible to assign this statement to the variable inside the function?

I need the functionality like those with `TG_NAME`, `TG_OP`, etc. in trigger procedures.

Maybe is it possible to retrieve this statement from SELECT current_query FROM pg_stat_activity ?

When I'm trying to use it inside a function I've got an empty record:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_snitch(text)
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
declare
rr text;
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE '.. from f_snitch.';
    -- do stuff
    SELECT current_query  into rr FROM pg_stat_activity 
    WHERE current_query ilike 'f_snitch';
    RETURN rr;
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Any help and suggestions would be happily welcome!

Comment: You can get the *top level* query with `SELECT current_query()` ... but that won't give you the immediate caller, it gives you the top level user statement. I'm not aware of any way to get the immediate calling statement; there isn't really a "stack" to examine.

Comment: Thanks, but current_query() gives me result: 'CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_snitch(text)' and I would like to have: 'SELECT f_snitch('foo')';

Answer (score 1):

`TG_NAME` and friends are special variables that only exist for trigger functions. Regular plpgsql functions don't have anything like that. I am fresh out of ideas how you could possibly get this inside the *called* function in plpgsql.

You *could* add `RAISE NOTICE` to your function so you get the desired information

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_snitch(text)
  RETURNS text LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE '.. from f_snitch.';
    -- do stuff
    RETURN 'Snitch says hi!';
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT f_snitch('foo')
```

In addition to the result, this returns a notice:

```
NOTICE:  .. from f_snitch.
```

Fails to please in two respects:

1. *Calling statement* is not in the notice.
2. No *CONTEXT* in the notice.

For **1.** you can use **`RAISE LOG`** instead (or set your cluster up to log NOTICES, too - which I usually don't, too verbose for me). With standard settings, you get an additional line with the `STATEMENT` in the database log:

```
LOG:  .. from f_snitch.
STATEMENT:  SELECT f_snitch('foo')
```

For **2.**, have a look at this [related question at dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/7214/3684). `CONTEXT` would look like:

```
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT f_raise('LOG', 'My message')"
    PL/pgSQL function "f_snitch" line 5 at PERFORM
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've got it!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_snitch(text)
  RETURNS setof record AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
    SELECT current_query 
    FROM pg_stat_activity 
    <strike>ORDER BY length(current_query) DESC LIMIT 1;</strike>
    where current_query ilike 'select * from f_snitch%';
    -- much more reliable solution

END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;

  select * from f_snitch('koper') AS (tt text);
```

And here is the result:

[image]

It's probably not 100% reliable solution but for small systems (for few users) it's quite ok.

Comment: That is going to produce random, bizarre and unexpected results when there are several concurrent sessions. You would need to filter by `pid = pg_backend_pid()` to exclude other sessions. I'm also not convinced it's actually correct.

Comment: I agree with you. That's why I changed the where clause and added a few new lines to function that catch the result of this one. In my case - considering system I'm developing - don't have to worry about multiple sessions executing this function. It's small, dedicated soft for a few people, but by bigger projects I have to agree - pid operations would be necessary.